# Visual Studio variables usable in config files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, environment-variables, app-config

$(ProjectDir) etc. are not being replaced in my Visual Studio C# project's app.config file.

I'm sure this is simple and I'm just searching for the wrong things, but does anyone know?

EDIT:
I want to have this work in my app.config:

```
<add key="path" value="$(ProjectDir)..\blabla">
```

Comment: What do you want to know? Where these enviromentvariables are set up?

Comment: $(ProjectDir) is a default VS variable it doesn't need to be set up. I want to use it.

Comment: Elaborate more please, you want to use it, in what way, where do you want to use it?

Comment: These `$(...)` are build variables recognized and used by Visual Studio during the build process. It seems that you want to use them in a config file but this is something that is used at runtime by your application thus these variables have no meaning to your application when run standalone outside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like `$(ProjectDir)` are *build-time* (or rather, design-time) environment variables for use within Visual Studio and the MSBuild build system. They have nothing to do with the applications you're building. Your `app.config` file is your program's runtime configuration file.

If you want to have text inside your app.config file vary when your project is built then you should look at T4 Templates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx -  that you can use VS's environment variables from within them (see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee848143(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee848143%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) under "Access to environment").

But in your case, it looks like you could just use relative paths in your application, why do you need to hardcode paths in your config file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$(ProjectDir)` in your `app.config`. The `app.config` file is already in the project directory so you can just use a relative path from there.

```
<add key="path" value="blabla">
```